# Removing slides of a presentation using officer package in R

Tags: r, officer

I am working with officer package in R to transfer my plots as outputs to a power point presentation.

Every time I run the code, I want to make sure that there are no slides in the pptx in which I want to save my plots.

Right now I know how to remove a single slide from the presentation. But I have no idea of how to remove all the slides at once.

My code so far is:

```
    library(officer)

    # reading template slides and adding slide in which I want my plot 

    doc <- read_pptx("U://30-Power & Water//25 Renewables//WORK//Config//Templates//Template.pptx")

    doc <- add_slide(doc, layout = "Title and Content",master = "Office Theme")
    doc <- ph_with_gg(doc, value = Sweihan ) #plot = ggplot

    # Reading the output slides and removing slides (it is just removing one slide so far)    

    output <- read_pptx("U://30-Power & Water//25 Renewables//WORK//Result//Result.pptx")

    output <-  remove_slide(output)

    print(output, target = "U://30-Power & Water//25 Renewables//WORK//Result//Result.pptx" ) %>% invisible()

    # tranfering results to output ppt file
    print(doc, target = "U://30-Power & Water//25 Renewables//WORK//Result//Result.pptx" ) %>% invisible()
```

what function can I use in my code using officer package to remove all the slides at once?

Your help will be appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for `index` argument in `remove_slide` is

> **Usage:**
>     remove_slide(x, index = NULL)
>
> *index* - slide index, default to current slide position

Hence, you can remove slide one at a time as follows:

```
for (n in rev(seq_len(length(output)))) {
    remove_slide(output, n)
}

#show number of slides
length(output)
```

Comment: I tried including your code and it didn't work as I wanted. length(output) is equals to 1 and thus only 1 slide got removed

Comment: the documentation mentions that `length` returns the number of slides. if it doesnt, you might want to file an issue at https://github.com/davidgohel/officer

Comment: now I understood how length() function is working. But your code isn't able to remove all slides at once. It is removing one slide only. I am getting this error: " Error: unvalid index 2 (1 slide(s)) "

Comment: how many slides do you have in your pptx? what does `length` gives you? it might be zero-indexed, which means that you need `n-1` instead.

Comment: that's no the case.

Comment: `length()`  giving me correct number of slides, but there is an issue when we apply lapply function. I am not sure why :/

Comment: i updated the code to delete in reverse sequence. seems like index is being refreshed with each `remove_slide`

Comment: yes it was doing that! it's working now. Thanks a lot @chinsoon12